# Phantomjs - why it is not multi-threaded

Tags: javascript, multithreading, phantomjs

I was trying to use Phantomjs in one of my projects. I have read about Phantomjs that it is single threaded and not multi-threaded. I want to use it in a multi-threaded environment.
The only part that is confusing me is: how can I make the PhantomJS work in a multi-threaded environment. If someone can let me know where exactly I need to change the phantom js so that it will work in a multi threaded environment, then it will be of great help.
This is the link from where I have downloaded the phantomjs folder:
http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Comment: Why is phantomjs being single threaded an issue? Do you need to manipulate phantomjs from multiple threads for some reason?

Comment: @JosephEarl Yes, I want to that's why I want to ask this question. I have also gone through various other questions on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), but I didn't got any answer or even a question to which I can relate my query.

Answer (score 0):

The [browser engine PhantomJS uses](http://phantomjs.org/supported-web-standards.html) is [QTWebkit](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit), a QT port of [Webkit](https://webkit.org/), which is [not thread safe](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html). So, in order to make PhantomJS thread safe it looks like you would need to start with it's underlying web browser engine.

My suggestion would be to use Selenium. Don't change or wrangle with PhantomJS, go up a level in your architecture and use that to manage the multiple browser drivers (there are options for [IPC](http://phantomjs.org/inter-process-communication.html)). If you need an environment to perform a "heavier lift" I would look at [Selenium-Grid 2.0](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp)

Of course, YMMV, There are other testing frameworks that may be better suited (NUnit/HtmlUnit, etc.) depending on your actual requirements or development environment.